# how to read all links one by one(webcrawling) from the file using java?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, web-crawler

files which contains all the links in one file and in have code to fetch the data from that links but this code only works for one link which we have mention there but, We want to execute all the links from that files which we stored in one file. one by one and same time it should store all the data which is fetching from that link and store in other text file.

```
    URL my_url = new URL("http://www.flipkart.com/");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(my_url.openStream()));
    String strTemp = "";
    while(null != (strTemp = br.readLine())){
    System.out.println(strTemp);                                        
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("/home/cloudera/Desktop/output.txt");      
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);  
    String s1;
    while((s1 = br.readLine() ) != null )
{
    bw.write(s1);
    bw.newLine();  
}
    System.out.println("success");
    bw.close(); 
    fw.close();
    //br.close();  
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Remove the second while and do bw.write(strTemp);

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Aviator!! I tried its not working. actually above code for single link and store output in LFS. but right now what I want to do is reading all links from one file and fetch the data from the link one by one and store into text files.

Answer (score 0):

You are reinventing the wheel. Unless it is a school assignement, why not just use an existing Java crawler like [Nutch](http://nutch.apache.org) or [StorCrawler](http://stormcrawler.net) instead of trying to solve problems that others have already taken care of?